# how to clear browser history in android pragmatically on All api level

Tags: android, database, caching, browser, android-contentprovider

I am working on a application where i need to clear browser history for all like chrome, Mozilla. 
I have tried following code but this is not working form me:

```
Browser.clearHistory(mContextUtility.getContentResolver());
```

Comment: What you want should not be possible, insofar as not all browsers used the `Browser` provider, and that provider itself is no longer available in Android. There is no requirement for a Web browser to provide an API for arbitrary other apps to delete the browser's history or other data.

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentResolver cR=getContentResolver();
if(Browser.canClearHistory(cR)){
   Browser.clearHistory(cR);
   Browser.clearSearches(cR);
}
```

You try with above code might be helpful

Comment: there is no such method in  Browser  class. is i am doing something wrong ?